# How to store data in internal memory of device in android programatically

Tags: android, data-storage

I have an app where i am supposed to store data that is entered in edittext.so what do i use to store data in internal memory of device?Plz help me out asap.

Comment: A little google could help you. Anyhow, read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help you,

[Using internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)